# How to generate set of arrays when clicking button, without disappearing the first one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Im trying to learn js. Im starting playing with array by generating 6 combination numbers. This is working but i dont know how to output another combinations when I click the button. Any comment is appreciated. THanks

```js
function getRandomNumber() {
    
  var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  var arr = [];
   while(arr.length < 8){
   var myrandomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random(x) * y + 1);
   if(arr.indexOf(myrandomnumber) === -1) arr.push(myrandomnumber);
    
  }

  if (x==""){
    alert("Please enter a number");
  }
  else if (y==""){
    alert("Please enter a number");
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = arr; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>RANDOM NUMBER JS</title>
        <meta name="" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cssextra/csse1.css">
        
        
        <script src="customscript.js"></script>
        </head>
    
    <body class="bg-light">
    <br>
    <p id="demo">Random Number</p>

    <br><br>
    <input type="number" id="num1" name="one"/  >
    <input type="number" id="num2" name="two"/  >
    <button onclick="getRandomNumber();">Generate random number</button >
    <p id="ok"></p><br>
    <p id="okok"></p>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like what you have should be working already. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: What I want is, everytime button i clicked a combination of number will appear. I have set it to 8 combi in the code but I want it to stay and it will not disappear when i click the button instead it will give another combinations.

Comment: So you want to list the combinations one below the other?

Comment: If you want 1 new number added to the list each time you click a button don't use a while loop. define `arr` outside of the `randomNumber()` function and push() only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Accumulate results

A easy yet crude solution would be appending the current text with `<br>` for line breaks:

```
const p = document.getElementById("ok");
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + (p.innerHTML === "" ? "" : "<br>") + arr.join(", ");
```

But this approach will notoriously perform badly as the text grows larger.

If you change the p elements into:

```
<div id="ok" class="text-container">
```

And replace the script's `document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = arr;` into:

```
const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = arr.join(", ");
document.getElementById("ok").appendChild(p);
```

And add css:

```
.text-container {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.text-container > p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then you should have something working.

Also there are some things to address:

### Math.random()

The function `Math.random()` does not take arguments, so your variable `x` does not have any effect.
If the intention is to x and y as a minimum and maximum value, try this from [Math.random() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  var min = Math.ceil(min);
  var max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

The `min` is inclusive and the `max` is exclusive. If `x = 0` and `y = 10`, and you want the range to be [0-10], you can do `getRandomInt(x, y + 1)`.
Make sure `min` is not greater than `max`.

### Prevent infinite loop

Your loop will get stuck if the amount of possible unique integers is smaller than the number of array elements required for it to end.

### More user input semantics

Variables `x` and `y` are tested before writing out the numbers, **but** after they have already been used to generate the numbers. In other words, the number creation process should be moved into the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` expects a string and you are setting the array.

use `document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = arr.join(' ');`

this will concatenate each element in the array with a space as glue